# Aligning stack variables in D

Tags: stack, alignment, d

In D, you can align struct/class members by using the `align` keyword, e.g.:

```
struct Vec4 { align(16) float[4] elems; }
```

However, it appears that you can't do the same on the stack:

```
void foo()
{
    align(16) float[4] vec; // error: found 'align' instead of statement
}
```

Is there a way to align data on the stack? In particular, I want to create an 16-byte aligned array of floats to load into XMM registers using [`movaps`](http://www.softeng.rl.ac.uk/st/archive/SoftEng/SESP/html/SoftwareTools/vtune/users_guide/mergedProjects/analyzer_ec/mergedProjects/reference_olh/mergedProjects/instructions/instruct32_hh/vc181.htm), which is significantly faster than [`movups`](http://www.softeng.rl.ac.uk/st/archive/SoftEng/SESP/html/SoftwareTools/vtune/users_guide/mergedProjects/analyzer_ec/mergedProjects/reference_olh/mergedProjects/instructions/instruct32_hh/vc206.htm).

e.g.

```
void foo()
{
    float[4] v = [1.0f, 2.0f, 3.0f, 4.0f];
    asm
    {
        movaps XMM0, v; // v must be 16-byte aligned for this to work.
        ...
    }
}
```

Comment: So that I can use `movaps` instead of `movups` in inline assembler.

Answer (score 5):

If you are willing to burn an extra 16 bytes you can do the alignment your self at run time. Aside from that, I wouldn't know.

Comment: Yeah, that's what I'm doing at the moment, although it's a bit ugly and wastes a few extra cycles.